# Find model records by column names in the order the array given

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using mysql. I have to show users record in particular manner which I mentioned as in value fields. I have to order by `user_id`, not by primary id. I need the objects in the following order: `[5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1]`.

I am using `pluck` to view particular column instead of object.

```
Project.where('user_id IN (?)', [5,4,2,1]).pluck(:user_id)
#=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

But the above query returns `[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5]` instead of `[5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1]`.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Have you tried: `Project.where('user_id IN (?)', [5,4,2,1]).order(user_id: :desc).pluck(:user_id)`?

Comment: I tried like you mentioned , But it is mot working.
Project.where('user_id IN (?)', [5,4,2,1]).pluck(:user_id) 
Getting -> [1,2,4,5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Rails query will sort the records by their ids. If you want to remain the order as the value fields, try to the following code.

```
user_ids = [5,4,2,1]
Project.where(user_id: user_ids).order("FIELD(user_id, #{user_ids.join(',')})").pluck(:user_id)
```